# How can I run code after webpage has loaded in JS (window.onload is failing me)?

Tags: javascript, html

Heyo,

I'm trying to create a script that opens a URL and sign in using the given credentials.

Therefore I created this:

```
window.open("https://stackoverflow.com/users/login");
document.getElementById('email').value = "ThisIsMy@Email.com";
document.getElementById('password').value = "ThisIsMyPassword";
document.getElementById('submit-button').click();
```

But then I changed the code to wait for the page to load using `window.onload`:

```
window.open("https://stackoverflow.com/users/login");
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('email').value = "ThisIsMy@Email.com";
    document.getElementById('password').value = "ThisIsMyPassword";
    document.getElementById('submit-button').click();
}
```

However, this does not seem to work.

Therefore I added some `console.log` into my code to debug, like this:

```
console.log("starting")
window.open("https://stackoverflow.com/users/login");
console.log("page open")
window.onload = function() {
    console.log("page loaded")
    document.getElementById('email').value = "ThisIsMy@Email.com";
    document.getElementById('password').value = "ThisIsMyPassword";
    document.getElementById('submit-button').click();
    console.log("signed in")
}
```

When I run the code in the console (Chrome/Firefox), I get back `started` and `page open`, but nothing else.
When I test the function isolated (i.e. the 3 different `document.getElementById`) it works just fine. Something must be wrong with the `window.onload` call?

From other sources here on StackOverflow I tried to use `document.onload` instead, and I also tried to use `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {...}`, but none of these seems to be working either.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

#newbie

Comment: window.open() opens a new tab. You'd have to be super fast to go to that tab and run your window.onload before it finishes loading

Comment: `window.onload` applies to the current window. Not the one created with `window.open()`. If you want to target that one, you need to use the return value of the `window.open()`. This however only works when you are on the [same origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). Otherwise the browser will not allow you to interact with the other page.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't access a cross origin page. What you are trying is only available to browser addons. And addons also require a specific permission granted by the user. For example the chrome permission to modify a webRequest: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/

`window.open()` returns the child window and this can be accessed IF it is `about:blank` or if the *same-origin-rule* applies (protocol, hostname and port - see pic below). Take a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anotherCoward/j8w0t926/) it shows something similar to what you are trying. (CORS 1)

Here you can see which child windows you may have access to. This means modify it on the fly or override it's content/location completly.

[image: Same Origin Policy]

The only method to communicate between two pages is: [`window.postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) and the [`window: Message-Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/message_event) which provides an easy to use API for communication.

Answer (score -1):

in your html page, in the `script` tag, where you call to your js page, add `defer`. like this:

```
<script src="your_script.js" defer></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! However, it did not work for me

Answer (score -1):

I would like to remind you it is not a very good idea to use password credentials inside javascript since it is hard to protect from public appearance.
I believe you can solve this kind of problem with programs such as Python, C++ , maybe Java , but Javascript is a Client-Side program which has some limitations but if you ask me these limitations actually makes it quite fun to use most of the time.

Comment: Python, C++ and Java are also client-side programs when you use them to enter credentials in a web-page.

Comment: yeah whatever you say

Comment: It is within a Chrome Extension so the default option here is JS/HTML/CSS